# CURRENT_TIME and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP give different results in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone, current-time

CURRENT_TIME and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP give different results in PostgreSQL. What is the reason of that? Why these are not in same timezone?

```
select current_timestamp, current_time;
```

results:

| current_time | current_timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 09:13:30 +0200 | 2023-08-03 10:13:30.122 +0300 |

Also my timezone is Europe/Istanbul.

```
SHOW TIMEZONE;
```

| TimeZone |
| --- |
| Europe/Istanbul |

Comment: Works for me: https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3zgeb5vy5 what is your setup? How can we reproduce this problem?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Images%20require%20more%20bandwidth%20than,byte%20and%20every%20millisecond%20count.)

Comment: it does not work for me @fukanchik

Comment: I removed the images and use txt exports. @UmutTEKİN

Comment: Don't use `current_time`. The documentation warns you about that.Anyway, what do you get for `SHOW timezone;`?

Comment: The problem might be the Turkish government' s ridiculous timezone policy. There should be a inconsistency between the real time you get and the date information that tzdb provides. Do you have access to operating system? If so, can you share `timedatectl` output and `date` output? If your server is connected a local NTP server that also could be the problem.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN I have a query that used current_timestamp. 
`select /*...*/
(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (current_timestamp - coalesce(d."LastStatusCheck", d."CreatedTime") )) / 60 )::integer as differenceInMinutes /*...*/`

This column gives positive value if I execute the query on DBeaver. It gives negative value If I execute with EFCore on Visual Studio debug mode.

Is this a bug on EFCore or EFCore PostgreSQL driver?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I shared `SHOW timezone` result on question description.

Comment: It works for me with the Turkish time zone. I have got the IANA time zone database version 2023a; what do you have?

Comment: Then it means client based. Do you have direct database server? Did you run `timedatectl` and `date`? Client can show different default behaviours, to be sure try to run these directly on the database server.

Answer (score -1):

In DBeaver you could setup Timezone in Preferences:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr39v.png

Comment: I don't think that helps to solve the problem.